# Match slightly different records in a field

Tags: sql, oracle, fuzzy-comparison

I have the below table HAVE. How can I go about getting results in "WANT" ? I'll appreciate ideas and I'm open to any fuzzy match algorithm out there

Have

```
ID Name   
1  Davi  
2  David 
3  DAVID
4  Micheal
5  Michael
6  Oracle
7  Tepper
```

WANT

```
ID Name mtch_ind  
1  Davi     1
2  David    1
3  DAVID    1
4  Micheal  2
5  Michael  2
6  Oracle   3
7 Tepper    4
```

TABLE DDL and record insert

```
CREATE TABLE HAVE (
  ID INTEGER,
  Name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO data VALUES ('1', 'Davi');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('2', 'David');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('3', 'DAVID');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('4', 'Micheal');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('5', 'Michael');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('6', 'Oracle');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('7', 'Tepper');
```

Comment: Can you please explain why Davi and David have same ranks?

Comment: "Davi" is repeated for ID 1,2 and 3. When any pattern from a string is matched with other they are ranked the same.

Comment: Check  SOUNDEX  (I don't have a way to check PL/SQL)

Comment: .>> When any pattern from a string is matched with other they are ranked the same. – VN'sCorner 

That means if There is D, Da, Dav, Db, Dc, Dab ... all of them to match?

Comment: @Srinika - I guess a pattern should have minimum 2 letters. Wait for the requestor to provide directions as current information has lots of ambiguity. SOUNDEX seems reasonable but would need PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks@VN'sCorner  UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY was what I was looking for. In contrast to soundex function, it requires 2 arguments for it to work which was something I was battling with.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `mtch_ind` is some sort of grouping of names into disjoint subsets of "similar" names. If so, the problem doesn't make sense. Equality of names, or equality of names if we ignore capitalization, are examples of **equivalence** relations. Equivalence relations are the only ones that allow such partitioning into disjoint subsets. Any kind of "similarity" of names other than equality is **not** an equivalence relation, because it is not **transitive**. Given any two names, we can get from one to the other through a sequence of names, at each step only changing one char.

Comment: Example: LORD and JANE have no letters in common. Suppose that the following are valid names (they aren't, but with patience one can find a similar illustration using realistic names). Your table has the following names: LORD, LOND, LAND, LANE, JANE. Are LORD and LOND similar? How about LOND and LAND? Etc. You will find that LORD and JANE must be in the same group, if LORD and LOND must be in the same group, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algo that I believe should work:

Step-1: Identify the close matches by using the Jaro Winkler nearest match with threshold math of 75%
select
h1.name
h2.name,
UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER (h1.name,h2.name) as match_confidence
from have h1
join have h2
on UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER (h1.name,h2.name) > 0.75--considering 75 % match threshold.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRfH9.png)

Step-2 : Pick h2.name where the match_confidence is maximum or one top row for similar records

for example 
[enter image description here][enter image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfG4f.png)

Step-3 : preform a dense rank operation on the new column to end up in the result you wanted.

Hope this works 
Note: First post on SO. I don't have access to the oracle at the moment.

Comment: Thanks you @sampath

Answer (score 0):

While this solution is a bit ugly, I came up with this approach. FYI, it's best to first convert uppercase DAVID to to David. Hopefully, someone may find this useful or come up with a better solution. Thanks

```
with table1 as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY firstID) as rowno,A.* FROM (
select 
t1.name
,t1.ID
, case when t1.ID>t1.Fid then fid else T1.ID end as FIRSTID 
, case when t1.ID>t1.Fid then T1.id else fID end as SECONDID 
, case when t1.ID>t1.Fid then t1.NAME else t1.FNAME end as FIRSTNAME
, case when t1.ID>t1.Fid then t1.FNAME  else t1.NAME  end as SECONDNAME
, case when count(*) over (partition by id) =1 then 'nodups' else 'dups' end as ID_chk
from (
SELECT h1.NAME,
 h1.ID, 
  h2.id as Fid,
  h2.name as Fname,
SYS.UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(h1.name,h2.name) as match1 
FROM (select 
NAME,
 ID from HAVE)h1 , (
select 
 NAME,
 ID FROM
have)
h2 where SYS.UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY((h1.name),(h2.name)) > 75
order by h1.id
)
t1

)A
)
, no_dups as
(
select * from table1 where ID_chk='nodups'
)
,dups as
(
select * from table1 where ID_chk<>'nodups'
)
, dups_stp1 as
(
select * from dups
WHERE FIRSTID <>  SECONDID
)
, dups_stp2 as 
(
select rowno,ID,FIRSTID,SECONDNAME from dups_stp1 
where FIRSTID not in (select SECONDID from dups_stp1)
)

  select t2.ID,t3.NAME,rnk as mtch_ind  from (
select ID,SECONDNAME as NAME, dense_rank() OVER ( ORDER BY SECONDNAME asc)as rnk from (
select distinct ID, FIRSTID, SECONDNAME  from dups_stp2
union all 
select ID, FIRSTID, SECONDNAME  from no_dups
)t1 
)t2
inner join HAVE t3 on t2.ID=t3.ID
;
```

Reference
https://www.decisivedata.net/blog/cleaning-messy-data-sql-part-1-fuzzy-matching-names