# match on several or any combination of fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have this table "HAVE" and I want the results in table WANT

HAVE

```
fname lname dob     sid gndr
john  doe  20200101  1  M
john  doe  20200101     M
john       20200101  1  M
      doe  20200101  1  M
john  doe  20200101  1  
Karen Doe  20200101  2  F
```

WANT (the new_id can be a rownum or the sid). Note sid is a unique identifier to a person

```
fname lname dob     sid gndr new_id
john  doe  20200101  1  M    1
john  doe  20200101     M    1
john       20200101  1  M    1
      doe  20200101  1  M    1
john  doe  20200101  1       1   
Karen Doe  20200101  2  F    2
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Though a promising question, you'll need to tell us what's the specific rule to match those rows.

Comment: any logic is okay

Comment: A combination of fname, lname,dob,uid and gndr is a definite match; A combo of uid and dob is a match; a combination of fname,lname,dob is a match. Finally, feel free to decide which other combinations are appropriate

Comment: You asked essentially the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599416/match-slightly-different-records-in-a-field In a comment there, I explained why the question didn't make sense. It doesn't make any more sense here. Suppose you have three rows where the DOB and the gender are the same. The names and SID are (John Doe, 1), (Mark Bush, 1), (Mark Bush, 2). The first and third row only have DOB (and gender) in common; both the name and the SID are different. But there is **another** row that connects them into the same NEW_ID. That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: And, to be clear: What doesn't make sense is that, to decide if (John Doe, 1) and (Mark Bush, 2) should still be considered "the same person" depends on what other rows may exist in the table. If there's one row (with the same DOB and gender) with (John Doe, 2) or perhaps (Mark Bush, 1) - or even a longer chain of "same person" pairs - then they are "the same person", but if such other rows aren't present, they aren't "the same person". This dependence on what may or may not exist in other rows is what makes the problem meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. Open to better solutions. Thanks

```
with HAVE_tmp as 
(
select t.*,rownum as seq from HAVE t
)
,TBL1 as
(
SELECT 
seq
, DOB
, SID
,first_value(FNAME ignore NULLS) over (partition by SID,DOB order by DOB) as fname
,first_value(LNAME ignore NULLS) over (partition by SID,DOB order by DOB) as lname
,first_value(GNDR ignore NULLS) over (partition by SID,DOB order by DOB) as GNDR
FROM HAVE_tmp  
where trim(SID) is not null and trim(DOB) is not null
)
,TBL2 as
(
select t2.*, 
first_value(SID ignore NULLS) over (partition by fname,lname order by SEQ) as ID_1
from (
select * from TBL1
union all 
select 
seq
, DOB
, SID
,FNAME
, LNAME
,GNDR
FROM HAVE_tmp  
where trim(SID) is  null or trim(DOB) is  null
)t2
)
,TBL_FINAL as
(
select t.FNAME,t.LNAME,t.DOB, t.SID,t.GNDR,t1.ID_1 as new_id
from HAVE_tmp t
inner join TBL2 t1  on
t.seq=t1.seq
)

select * from TBL_FINAL
```